# while sending contact form 7 select option value why am getting null values to database in mysql?

Tags: wordpress

while sending contact form 7 select option value why am getting null values to database in mysql?
Site link:`https://www.submitmyclips.com/test-form/ form:`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhzco.png`Database:`https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mi4d.png`

Any solution please help

Answer (score 0):

You have given the Website URL, which is showing an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSLSY.png)

You can use the contact form 7 DB plugin for this, as the contact form is not storing its value in the Database, we need to use the Addon plugin for the same.

This is the link for your reference, please let me know if you have any query.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/

Comment: Thanks for reply
please check again: https://www.submitmyclips.com/test-form/

Comment: @AmitKoundal May I know how you are trying to save DB in the Database? 
as Contact form 7 does not provide its data into the database, It always shares the data with emails.

Please check this for your reference. 
https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/wordpress-form-to-database/#:~:text=Contact%20Form%207%20Database%20Addon%2C%20CFDB7%20for%20short%2C%20is%20a,burden%20you%20with%20unnecessary%20options.

Comment: We can add contact form details to DB through Function file DB Hook
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {